# Android: Custom LinearLayoutManager not allowing recyclerView to scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am using a custom LinearLayoutManager to disable/enable scrolling for my recyclerView.

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
        this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```

When I use this to set my RecyclerView, its not scrolling at all even when I set isScrollEnabled to true.

```
    CustomLayoutManager customLayoutManager = new CustomLayoutManager(getActivity());
    customLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(customLayoutManager);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm gonna ask the obvious question: Does it work if you use a normal `LinearLayoutManager`? And do you at some point set it to `false`, or is it always `true` but still not working?

Comment: The scroll is working with normal LinearLayoutManager. If I set it to a CustomLinearLayoutManager, its not scrolling anymore.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/mustafasevgi/7dcb18166aaf9944e6450ec2878a646a

hi 
this code works just fine but i cant make circle Recycleview mathparent

```
public class Layoutmameger extends LayoutManager{

private static int INTERVAL_ANGLE = 50;// The default interval angle between each items
private static float DISTANCE_RATIO = 20f; // Finger swipe distance divide item rotate angle

//Flags of scroll dirction
private static int SCROLL_LEFT = 1;
private static int SCROLL_RIGHT = 2;

private Context context;

// Size of each items
private int mDecoratedChildWidth;
private int mDecoratedChildHeight;

//Property
private int startLeft;
private int startTop;
private int mRadius;
private int intervalAngle;
private float offsetRotate; // The offset angle for each items which will change according to the scroll offset

//the range of remove from parent
private int minRemoveDegree;
private int maxRemoveDegree;

//initial position of content
private int contentOffsetX = -1;
private int contentOffsetY = -1;

private int firstChildRotate = 0;

//Sparse array for recording the attachment and rotate angle of each items
private SparseBooleanArray itemAttached = new SparseBooleanArray();
private SparseArray<Float> itemsRotate = new SparseArray<>();


public Layoutmameger(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    intervalAngle = INTERVAL_ANGLE;
    offsetRotate = 0;
    minRemoveDegree = -90;
    maxRemoveDegree = 90;
}


@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (getItemCount() == 0) {
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
        offsetRotate = 0;
        return;
    }

    //calculate the size of child
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);
        addView(scrap);
        measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);
        mDecoratedChildWidth = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(scrap);
        mDecoratedChildHeight = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(scrap);
        startLeft = contentOffsetX == -1?(getHorizontalSpace() - mDecoratedChildWidth)/2: contentOffsetX;
        startTop = contentOffsetY ==-1?0: contentOffsetY;
        mRadius = mDecoratedChildHeight;
        detachAndScrapView(scrap, recycler);
    }

    //record the state of each items
    float rotate = firstChildRotate;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        itemsRotate.put(i,rotate);
        itemAttached.put(i,false);
        rotate+= intervalAngle;
    }

    detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
    fixRotateOffset();
    layoutItems(recycler,state);
}

private void layoutItems(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,RecyclerView.State state){
    layoutItems(recycler,state,SCROLL_RIGHT);
}

private void layoutItems(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,
                         RecyclerView.State state,int oritention){
    if(state.isPreLayout()) return;

    //remove the views which out of range
    for(int i = 0;i<getChildCount();i++){
        View view =  getChildAt(i);
        int position = getPosition(view);
        if(itemsRotate.get(position) - offsetRotate>maxRemoveDegree
                || itemsRotate.get(position) - offsetRotate< minRemoveDegree){
            itemAttached.put(position,false);
            removeAndRecycleView(view,recycler);
        }
    }

    //add the views which do not attached and in the range
    for(int i=0;i<getItemCount();i++){
        if(itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate<= maxRemoveDegree
                && itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate>= minRemoveDegree){
            if(!itemAttached.get(i)){
                View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(i);
                measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);
                if(oritention == SCROLL_LEFT)
                    addView(scrap,0);
                else
                    addView(scrap);
                float rotate = itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate;
                int left = calLeftPosition(rotate);
                int top = calTopPosition(rotate);
                scrap.setRotation(rotate);
                layoutDecorated(scrap, startLeft + left, startTop + top,
                        startLeft + left + mDecoratedChildWidth, startTop + top + mDecoratedChildHeight);
                itemAttached.put(i,true);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int willScroll = dx;

    float theta = dx/DISTANCE_RATIO; // the angle every item will rotate for each dx
    float targetRotate = offsetRotate + theta;

    //handle the boundary
    if (targetRotate < 0) {
        willScroll = (int) (-offsetRotate*DISTANCE_RATIO);
    }
    else if (targetRotate > getMaxOffsetDegree()) {
        willScroll = (int) ((getMaxOffsetDegree() - offsetRotate)*DISTANCE_RATIO);
    }
    theta = willScroll/DISTANCE_RATIO;

    offsetRotate+=theta; //increase the offset rotate so when re-layout it can recycle the right views

    //re-calculate the rotate x,y of each items
    for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
        View view = getChildAt(i);
        float newRotate = view.getRotation() - theta;
        int offsetX = calLeftPosition(newRotate);
        int offsetY = calTopPosition(newRotate);
        layoutDecorated(view, startLeft + offsetX, startTop + offsetY,
                startLeft + offsetX + mDecoratedChildWidth, startTop + offsetY + mDecoratedChildHeight);
        view.setRotation(newRotate);
    }

    //different direction child will overlap different way
    if (dx < 0)
        layoutItems(recycler, state,SCROLL_LEFT);
    else
        layoutItems(recycler,state,SCROLL_RIGHT);
    return willScroll;
}

/**
 *
 * @param rotate the current rotate of view
 * @return the x of view
 */
private int calLeftPosition(float rotate){
    return (int) (mRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - rotate)));
}

/**
 *
 * @param rotate the current rotate of view
 * @return the y of view
 */
private int calTopPosition(float rotate){
    return (int) (mRadius - mRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 - rotate)));
}

private int getHorizontalSpace() {
    return getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
}

private int getVerticalSpace() {
    return getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
}

/**
 *  fix the offset rotate angle in case item out of boundary
 **/
private void fixRotateOffset() {
    if(offsetRotate < 0){
        offsetRotate = 0;
    }
    if(offsetRotate > getMaxOffsetDegree()){
        offsetRotate = getMaxOffsetDegree();
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return the max degrees according to current number of views and interval angle
 */
private float getMaxOffsetDegree(){
    return (getItemCount()-1)* intervalAngle;
}

private PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    final int firstChildPos = getPosition(getChildAt(0));
    final int direction = targetPosition < firstChildPos ? -1 : 1;
    return new PointF(direction, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
    if(position < 0 || position > getItemCount()-1) return;
    float targetRotate = position * intervalAngle;
    if(targetRotate == offsetRotate) return;
    offsetRotate = targetRotate;
    fixRotateOffset();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return Layoutmameger.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }
    };
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}

@Override
public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
    removeAllViews();
    offsetRotate = 0;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 *
 * @return Get the current positon of views
 */
public int getCurrentPosition(){
    return Math.round(offsetRotate / intervalAngle);
}

/**
 *
 * @return Get the dx should be scrolled to the center
 */
public int getOffsetCenterView(){
    return (int) ((getCurrentPosition()*intervalAngle-offsetRotate)*DISTANCE_RATIO);
}

/**
 *
 * @return Get the radius of the circle
 */
public int getRadius() {
    return mRadius;
}

/**
 *
 * @param mRadius the radius of the circle,default will be item's height
 */
public void setRadius(int mRadius) {
    this.mRadius = mRadius;
}

/**
 *
 * @return the interval angle between each items
 */
public int getIntervalAngle() {
    return intervalAngle;
}

/**
 * Default angle is 30
 * @param intervalAngle the interval angle between each items
 */
public void setIntervalAngle(int intervalAngle) {
    this.intervalAngle = intervalAngle;
}

/**
 * Default is center in parent
 * @return the content offset of x
 */
public int getContentOffsetX() {
    return contentOffsetX;
}

/**
 * Default is center in parent
 * @param contentOffsetX the content offset of x
 */
public void setContentOffsetX(int contentOffsetX) {
    this.contentOffsetX = contentOffsetX;
}

/**
 * Default is top in parent
 * @return the content offset of y
 */
public int getContentOffsetY() {
    return contentOffsetY;
}

/**
 * Default is top in parent
 * @param contentOffsetY the content offset of y
 */
public void setContentOffsetY(int contentOffsetY) {
    this.contentOffsetY = contentOffsetY;
}

/**
 * Default is 0
 * @return the rotate of first child
 */
public int getFirstChildRotate() {
    return firstChildRotate;
}

/**
 * Default is 0
 * @param firstChildRotate the rotate of first child
 */
public void setFirstChildRotate(int firstChildRotate) {
    this.firstChildRotate = firstChildRotate;
}

/**
 * The rotate of child view in range[min,max] will be shown,default will be [-90,90]
 * @param min min rotate that will be show
 * @param max max rotate that will be show
 */
public void setDegreeRangeWillShow(int min,int max){
    if(min > max) return;
    minRemoveDegree = min;
    maxRemoveDegree = max;
}
```

}

Comment: Please give more detail and describe your changes to original code

Comment: this is how Circle Recycle View works   https://medium.com/@v.danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d